# OpenFileDialog freezes when called from another dialog

Tags: c#, winforms

I have forms: `Splashscreen`, `Search`, and `NewEntry`

`Program.cs` starts `Splashscreen` which checks some parameters and upon success (check user name, permissions, etc) opens `Search` form. From there I can call the `NewEntry` form.

So since the `Splashscreen` is the primary form called by the `Main()` function, once it closes, the app closes (this is the expected behaviour).
So what I did is from within `Splashscreen` I start the `Search` form as a dialog and hide `Splashscreen`, so it waits for the `Search` to close. As soon as it closes, I also close the `Splashscreen` and it all seemed to make sense at the time. From the `Search` form I open the `NewEntry` form (from a button click) also as a dialog (I don't want users clicking back and forth and creating multiple `NewEntry` windows).

Today I had to add a feature that allows the user to select a file. As an obvious choice, I used an `OpenFileDialog`. But as soon as I call `.ShowDialog()` method, the whole app just freezes.

I've read [Windows Forms GUI hangs when calling OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718148/windows-forms-gui-hangs-when-calling-openfiledialog-showdialog) and [OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() freezing application c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773411/openfiledialog-showdialog-freezing-application-c-sharp) and a bunch of other posts here and on other sites, and when I almost lost hope, I came across this http://wishmesh.com/2011/06/call-to-openfiledialog-or-savefiledialog-hangs-or-freezes/
I do have the `[STAThread]` attribute set on my `Main()` function

And one particular point of interest is: ***For OpenFileDialog the ShowHelp property must be explicitly set.***
And also ***... They don’t have to be set to true, they just have to be initialized to either true or false.***

So when I set the `ShowHelp` to `true`, the dialog shows up (with the useless Help button).

A further research showed that when I execute `(new OpenFileDialog()).ShowDialog();` within `Program.cs` or within `Splashscreen`, it works just fine; however, when called from a dialog, there is a hang (without the `ShowHelp`). Furthermore, a `MessageBox` shows up just fine from the `Dialog`...

So is there a way to make this work? Or should I manage my windows differently?
For example, have `Search` as the main startup window, then before the window shows, call `Splashscreen` as a dialog, and if it fails, just close the main window? But then, how would I handle the `NewEntry` to be able to show `OpenFileDialog` or `FolderBrowserDialog`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in your `program.cs`, you are calling this: `Application.Run(new splashscreen());`, if it were me, I would do this instead so that you can have multiple forms open after the splashscreen closes.

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        new splashscreen().ShowDialog(); 
        Application.Run(new Search());
    }
}
```

This will show the splashscreen, and then once everything's loaded, you can open the search form and close the splashscreen, and won't have to call `ShowDialog()`. (you'll have to call `application.End()` to end the application.)

Comment: I implemented this suggestion and the only part that seems incorrect is that even when the last window is closed, the application does not end. Windows Task manager shows that process as still running and the debugger does not return to "normal" mode, I have to click the "Stop" button. But this seems like an easy fix and an good alternative to what I had. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Sorry for the inline code, can't format much in the comment. This is what I have right now: `if ((new Splashscreen()).ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) { (new Search()).Show(); Application.Run(); }`  I close the window bu pressing the "X" in the top right corner and I do not handle the `Close`, `Closing`, etc methods that could override and minimise instead of closing...

Comment: I guess, if I change what I have into `Application.Run(new Search());`, this should work. I will be hiding the `Search` window and showing the `NewEntry` while setting the `ParentForm` property and handling all as per @Scott MacMaster's suggestion

Comment: @nurchi, my bad, you'll actually have to call `Application.End()` in the `closing` or `closed` event handlers in the last form to close (I had looked at a multi-form project I just made, and didn't realize I was ending the application in my 'mainform' when it was closed).

Comment: @nurchi, I updated my answer so that the splashscreen will show, and once it closes, the application will run, with search as its mainform.

Answer (score 3):

The part that concerns me the most is when you say you have SplashScreen wait for Search to close.  If you are doing this

```
if (search.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Show();
}
```

Then you have frozen the UI thread for the SplashScreen.  Since it's the main form things are not likely to work as expected.  I suggest changing the code to this.

```
Hide(); // Hides SplashScreen
Search search = new Search();
search.ParentForm = this;
search.Show(); // Show Search without freezing SplashScreen thread
```

ParentForm is a public variable I added to Search.  This should be private and access should be through a getter/setter but this keeps the code example short.

```
public partial class Search: Form
{
    public SplashScreen ParentForm;
    ...
}
```

Next you will need to add a handler to handle the Search form closing.  This will show SplashScreen.

```
private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    ParentForm.Show();
}
```

After making these changes OpenFileDialog show work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first part although not identical, is not much different, I was doing: `this.Hide(); (new Search()).ShowDialog(); this.Close();`. The main difference is that I don't care much about the `DialogResult` of the `Search` form, I just want it to act like the "main window" of the app. I'll give a try to your suggestions and keep this post updated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I really appreciate your help in this matter.

So to summarise, I created `Form1` and `Form2` to test some code and here is what I have (only relevant portions):

```
// Form1:
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2=new Form2();
    this.Hide();
    f2.Show(this);
}

// Form2:
void Form2Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Owner==null) throw new ArgumentException("This window must be called with the Owner property set!");
    // or just ignore, or show a MessageBox and close, or use your imagination...
}

void Form2FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    // sanity check...
    if (this.Owner!=null && !this.Owner.Visible) this.Owner.Show();
}
```

So when I call `Form2`, I first hide the current form and use an overload of `Show()` that takes 1 argument and sets the `Form2`'s `Owner` property. Alternately I could just call `f2.Owner=this;` and then `f2.Show();`

Then when/after `Form2` is closed, I check if Owner was set and show that form.

Now back to the original question, here is what I have inside `Program.cs`:

```
if ((new Splashscreen()).ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    Application.Run(new Search());
```

So now `Search` only shows if `Splashscreen` returned with `DialogResult.OK` and when `Search` is closed, the application exits properly.

Thanks for all the help.
This saved me tons of time.

P.S.
I wish I could mark both answers as **answers**, going to toss a coin and randomly mark one.

Comment: @ScottMacMaster and nurchi, I know how that feels, nurchi, with two good answers, and since mine was the lucky one, I'm going to go ahead and upvote Scott's (but I'm mostly going to because I actually thought it seems like it was more relevant to the final solution).