# openFileDialog.ShowDialog() didnt show dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, openfiledialog

I try to open System file dialog to select a pic. the code ran normally in my computer. But in another computer cant show the system file dialog.

And here is my simple code:-

```
private void PicInputBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog
    {
        DefaultExt = ".jpg",
        Filter = "img file|*.jpg",
    };

    if (dialog.ShowDialog() != true)
    {
        return;
    }
｝
```

Comment: Have you already tried the answers in this similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201227/c-wpf-openfiledialog-does-not-appear ?

Comment: Look at event viewer > windows logs> application. There should be an error log

Comment: @Sayse The `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog` returns a `bool?`. The code is ok. You are thinking of the `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog`

Comment: What happened on this other computer?

Comment: This is code from Microsoft : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If nothing happens but the mouse pointer turning into a little busy-indicator.

You can try to set your thread to `STAThread`:

```
[STAThread]    
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var o = new OpenFileDialog();
    var r = o .ShowDialog();
}
```

Howover they are many reasons that can break the `OpenFileDialog`, you can try to launch your program in admin mode and try to reinstall .net Framework

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
private void PicInputBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog
    {
        DefaultExt = ".jpg",
        Filter = "img file|*.jpg" // You had an extra ',' here.
    };

    if ((Nullable<bool>dialog.ShowDialog()) == true) // Also you forgot to put Nullable<bool>
    {
        // string filename = dlg.FileName;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
｝
```

Comment: Maybe not the code question,I ask my teammate to download the win7 sp1 patch and her computer can show the OpenFileDialog correctly! anyway,still thanks for your anwser!!!

Comment: @Fireyu That's okay.